# Pandas DataFrame Isnull Multiple Columns at Once

Tags: python, pandas, isnull

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,1,2],'b':[np.nan,np.nan,4]})

     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  NaN
2  2.0  4.0
```

How do I return rows where both columns 'a' and 'b' are null without having to use `pd.isnull` for each column?

Desired result:

```
     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
```

I know this works (but it's not how I want to do it):

```
df.loc[(pd.isnull(df['a']) & (pd.isnull(df['b'])]
```

I tried this:

```
df.loc[pd.isnull(df[['a', 'b']])]
```

...but got the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close:

```
df[~pd.isnull(df[['a', 'b']]).all(1)]
```

Or

```
df[df[['a','b']].isna().all(1)]
```

How about:

```
df.dropna(subset=['a','b'], how='all')
```

Comment: @DanceParty2 was just about to update. Done!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. Also, what does .all(1) do?

Comment: that's shorthand for `all(axis=1)`, i.e. checking row-wise, default is `axis=0`, checking column-wise.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using `isnull` function here.

```
mask1 = df['a'].isnull()
mask2 = df['b'].isnull()
df[mask1 & mask2]
```

---

---

Above answer is with creating 2 variables for better understanding. In case you want to use conditions inside df itself and don't want to create condition variables(`mask1` and `mask2` in this case) then try following.

```
df[df['a'].isnull() & df['b'].isnull()]
```

Output will be as follows.

```
    a   b
0   NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dropna()` with parameter as `how=all`

```
df.dropna(how='all')
```

Output:

```
   a    b
1  1.0  NaN
2  2.0  4.0
```

Since the question was updated, you can then create masking either using `df.isnull()` or using `df.isna()` and filter accordingly.

```
df[df.isna().all(axis=1)]
   a   b
0 NaN NaN
```

Comment: The question was updated.. I'll update the answer accordingly